# How do I do a htaccess rewrite to another folder for a single file?

Tags: .htaccess

We moved a part of our site from one sub folder to another. I want to put permanent redirects (301) into htaccess for the files in this folder (some have changed their filename as well, so I can't just setup one rule for the whole folder). Here's what I'm trying

```
RewriteRule ^search/tutorial-search.html$ db/tutorial.php [R=301]
```

This doesn't work though, I get a 404 response when now entering the old URL. I find this curious as I had a rule in place for ages that does work, which looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/tutorial-search.html$ search/tutorial-search.php
```

I really don't see the big difference. I also tried the following (among others) but it doesn't work either

```
RewriteRule ^search/tutorial-search.html$ db/tutorial.php
```

What exactly is causing this to fail? Just to make sure I put all of these at the exact same line of the htaccess file. Is it because I'm rewriting to another folder? Thanks :)

Comment: update: it was a later (third-party) part of the .htaccess overwriting the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a leading slash to your rewrite targets, because when redirecting, apache could be mistaking a URL-path with a file-path.

```
RewriteRule ^search/tutorial-search.html$ /db/tutorial.php [R=301]
```

Comment: @janb Does going to `http://yourdomain.com/db/tutorial.php` result in a 404? Is your htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: No, accessing the URL directly does not result in a 404, I made sure of that. Yes, the htaccess is in the root and definitely active. As I said, if I replace the line with what I had earlier (2nd code snippet), then that works as intended. But that's the old redirect and not correct anymore for our new folder structure.

Comment: @janb Do you have other rules that could be rewriting the URI after the redirect rule? Have you tried adding a `L` flag? So that it looks like `[L,R=301]`?

Comment: yeah tried that, didn't help. No other rules that should be affecting this one really :/ I actually have a second tutorial file in the same folders and that ones rewrite rule is right next to this one and works just fine. No differences between them really. Quite weird. I guess I have no choice but to build up a new htaccess from scratch and see where it starts to fail.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it is correct, even though it wasn't the solution for my problem.